# Extraer imagènes de tipo image de una base de datos

Tags: c#, sql-server

Estoy trabajando con la base de datos northwind y quiero extraer las imágenes de la tabla Employees para luego guardarlas en una carpeta, estuve intentando usar el comando bcp, pero parece que tuve errores con mi servidor de base de datos y no se ejecutaba correctamente.
¿Que método podría usar para poder extraer esos datos y guardarlos ya sea en formato jpg o png?
Estoy trabajando con SQL server y c#.

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: buenas sin codigo es dificil saber exactamente que necesitas, lo que te puedo decir por experiencia en sql server, es que te devuelve una byte array y después lo pues convertir a bitmap para grabarlo en físico (nota el formato interno sigue siendo jpg, png etc.).  Para saber con qual extensión grabarlo tienes que comprobar los headers.

Comment: Las columnas tipo image no guardan imágenes. Guardan datos binarios que pueden corresponder a cualquier valor o archivo. Para extraer los datos, es necesario usar el proceso inverso al que se usó para guardarlos.